# element:hover is not changing display to block

Tags: html, css

Unfortunately it wont display my drop-down nav block on hover, hope someone can help. I'm trying to change display:none to display: block on the class .moreMenu.

[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuiTn.png)

[css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZElHR.png)

Here is my code...

HTML

```html
    <div class="navigationBar">
    <div class = "navigationBarTitles">
        <a href="home.html">HOME</a>
        <a href="verbs.html">VERBS</a>
        <a href="nouns.html">NOUNS</a>
        <a href="adverbs.html">ADVERBS</a>
        <a href="adjectives.html">ADJECTIVES</a>
        <a href="grammar.html">GRAMMAR</a>
        <a href="contact.html" class= "more">MORE
            <div class="moreMenu">
                <a href="grammar.html">TRIAL VIDEOS</a>
                <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
                <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
                <a href="grammar.html">GCSE EXAM PREP</a>
                <a href="grammar.html">PLANS & PRICING</a>
                <a href="grammar.html">GRAMMAR</a>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
```

CSS

```css
     .moreMenu {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        width: 140px;
        height: 180px;
        background-color: white;
        z-index: 2;
      }

    .more:hover .moreMenu {
        display: block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your HTML: you can't nest interactive elements. Since the .moreMenu div contains <a> elements, and is itself contained in an <a> element, it won't work.

Solution: don't put the <div> inside the MORE link, but put them next to each other in a container.

```css
.more {
  display: inline;
}

.moreMenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 140px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 2;
}

.more:hover .moreMenu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="navigationBar">
    <div class="navigationBarTitles">
      <a href="home.html">HOME</a>
      <a href="verbs.html">VERBS</a>
      <a href="nouns.html">NOUNS</a>
      <a href="adverbs.html">ADVERBS</a>
      <a href="adjectives.html">ADJECTIVES</a>
      <a href="grammar.html">GRAMMAR</a>
      <div class="more"><a href="contact.html">MORE</a>
        <div class="moreMenu">
          <a href="grammar.html">TRIAL VIDEOS</a>
          <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
          <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
          <a href="grammar.html">GCSE EXAM PREP</a>
          <a href="grammar.html">PLANS &amp; PRICING</a>
          <a href="grammar.html">GRAMMAR</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks! I get what you mean, I had to contain it within a div, cheers dude its working great now.